# Its not working.Switching bootstrap icons using click, if else(JS)

Tags: javascript

The two icons should be swap when I clicked it.

Here is the code that I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#navbar-mobile").click(function() {
        $('.view-mobile').slideToggle('fast');
    });
if($('#navbar-mobile').click(function(){
     $('#menu-icons').addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle");
    $('#menu-icons').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger");
        }else{
    $('#menu-icons').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle");
    $('#menu-icons').addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger");
   }););
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toggle class,  [ref](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) , [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp)

```
$("#navbar-mobile").click(function() {
       $('#menu-icons').toggleClass('ClassName');
    });
```

If you need if else condition , please check below code as reference

```
$("#navbar-mobile").click(function() {
    if(  $("#menu-icons").hasClass('main') ){
      alert('yes');
    }else{
      alert('no');
    }
});
```